# Make a selection based on difference in dates

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to make a select based on difference in date in the 2 tables. I am only interested in looking at values where the difference in date is at plus/minus one day. Something like:

```
select aa.*
from A aa
inner join B bb on aa.ID=bb.ID
where difference(aa.date and bb.date) is +- 1 day
```

What I mean by +- one day is:

Plus one day (one day between aa.date and bb.date)

```
aa.date = 02-01-2020  (January 2nd)
bb.date = 03-01-2020  (January 3rd)
```

Minus one day (one day between aa.date and bb.date)

```
aa.date = 02-01-2020  (January 2nd)
bb.date = 01-01-2020  (January 1st)
```

---

More than one day (and not interested in this value)

```
aa.date = 02-01-2020  (January 2nd)
bb.date = 04-01-2020  (January 1st)

or
aa.date = 02-01-2020  (January 2nd)
bb.date = 31-12-2019  (December 31st)
```

Hope this makes sense
Thanks for any help

Comment: You should provide sample data and explain what YOU mean by "+- 1 day".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `abs` function as following:

```
select aa.*
from A aa inner join B bb
  on aa.ID = bb.ID
 And abs(aa.date - bb.date) <= 1;
```

Cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

You can use date arithmetic in the `on` clause:

```
select aa.*
from A aa inner join
     B bb
     on aa.ID = bb.ID and
        aa.date >= bb.date - interval '1' day and
        aa.date <= bb.date + interval '1' day;
```